# Top pie and ele?

Tags: word

You have to find a word that ends in the hashtag-ed word  and starts with the word described. I will describe the first word and then the whole word including the hashtag-ed word.
For example if I say it ends with top and say “where you put your computer while you are sitting on the couch” you would say **laptop**.

### #Top

> Something you wear in the summer to play baseball.
>
> Something you may clean your convertible with.

### #Ele

> Every form of a certain gene.
>
> Enlightenment coiner who plays an European instrument.

### #And

> A powerful function that keeps growing.
>
> A type of road that is erected.

### #Pie

> A rich millennial who agrees.
>
> Something tasty you may not cook in a pan.

Hope you guys enjoyed this, feedback appreciated!

Comment: Very interesting style of question... so do we call this a Quantum- riddle or a Twinkie-riddle? 

Comment: Hmm, I do not know. My name is kind of long! :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Something you wear in the summer to play baseball.

> **Shortstop**

> Something you may clean your convertible with.

> **Ragtop**

> Every form of a certain gene.

> **Allele**

> Enlightenment coiner who plays an European instrument.

> **Kantele**

> A powerful function that keeps growing.

> **Expand**

> A type of road that is erected.

> **Stand** (found by hagfy)

> A rich millennial who agrees.

> **Yuppie**

> Something tasty you may not cook in a pan.

> **Potpie**

Comment: Yup those are correct, one more to go.

Comment: I think it might just be rot13-'fgnaq' ('fg' sbe fgerrg naq rerpg = fgnaq)?

Comment: That is promising @hagfy :D

Comment: @hagfy Nice find! Should you write it as an answer?

Comment: @noedne Nope, just trying to help.  =)   If you like it, it's yours!  If it's bad...I still don't want it.